# merge similar values in a row on python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge row cell values that are similar for example I have:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1lVe.png)

Where there are multiple values that are similar and I would like to get
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx5Ng.png)

by taking the average value of similar cells in a row or a lesser option would be to take the first of the similar values in each row.

I tried rounding the values to 3 decimal places, dropping duplicates and then rounding back to 4 decimal places but then I lost the resolution and merging the similar values would be preferable.

many thanks for any idea

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: So far I tried rounding the df, using df.round (2) thenreplacing duplicates with NaN and df.round(4) to return to the original resolution but this did not work and ideally the mean of the similar data would be more accurate.

Comment: I see you are new here - welcome! Usually we provide a snippet of code that shows what you've tried, since maybe you are doing the right thing but have a typo or something.  Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  That said, I've answered below.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i gave each row a name and melted

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name'])
```

#added duplicated the value column

```
df['d'] = df['value']
```

#rounded the new column

```
 df.round({'d':3,})
```

#grouped the df

```
 df.groupby(['name', 'd']).mean()
```

#after I pivoted the table on name